# This action couldn’t be completed. Try again later. [OR-CBAT-15]

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I can't link my billing account to the cards.

> Uh oh, something went wrong
> This action couldn’t be completed. Try again later. [OR-CBAT-15]

I have re-created my billing account several times, I keep getting this error, although card verification is going well, how do I solve this problem? And why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  It appears that you are looking for support for some vendor system, in which case you have found yourself in the wrong place.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)